# Mongo DB php driver fatal error

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I want to use Mongo DB with php, so for that I have installed the driver and its showing here as well in `phpinfo()`
[image]

The problem is when I try to connect it, I get Fatal error.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found`

Here is how I am connecting

```
$mongo = new \MongoDB\Client('mongodb://user:xxx!@00.00.00.00/chat');
    try
    {
        $dbs = $mongo->listDatabases();
        print_r($dbs);
    }
```

Here is how I installed extension `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mongodb`
Also I followed this http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php 
Any help!

Comment: I followed this http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

Comment: Please edit the question instead of commenting on it. Also add the command you was using to install the extension. `MongoDB\Client` is from the legacy library long deprecated by now.

Comment: done, I edited my question...

Comment: You are using tutorial for legacy library. You need http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php

Answer (score -1):

`\MongoDB\Client` belongs to the [mongo-php-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) which is different from [mongo-php-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver)

in another words, the library is using the driver,

so after installing the mongo-php-driver you need to perform another operation by installing the library using composer

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

or even by cloning it from github

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library.git
```